# getting data from unbinded view and submitting form data with linq into tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, entity-framework, linq

I have a form view which is not bound to any action or class. I want to get data of that form and insert into my tables through action using `LINQ`

```
@Html.BeginForm("New", "User", "GET")
{   
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Editor("Name", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("Name", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Email", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Editor("Email", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("Email", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

#### Controller "new "

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult New(FormCollection _col)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string name =_col["Name"].ToString();

        //db.tbl_User.Add(_col);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("New", "User", FormMethod.Post))
{

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "You may encounter some error as shown below:")

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.Editor("Name", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessage("Name", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Email", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.Editor("Email", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessage("Email", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
}
```

**CS**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult New(FormCollection _col)
    {
        using (DBContext db = new DBContext())
        {
            ValidateFormCollection(_col);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                User user = new User();
                user.Name = _col["Name"].ToString();
                user.Email = _col["Email"].ToString();

                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return View("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }

    private void ValidateFormCollection(FormCollection _col)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_col["Name"].ToString()))
            ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "The Name field is required.");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_col["Email"].ToString()))
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "The Email field is required.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follows,

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("New", "User", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Editor("Name", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("Name", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Email", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Editor("Email", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("Email", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
        </div>

    }
```

To insert into table, Easiest way is to create a class as same as your table fields, and then add `_col` values to that class and `db.tbl_User.Add(class you created);`

for example,

```
public Class TbleUser{
   public string name {get; set;}
   public string anotherField {get; set;}
}
```

then inside controller,

```
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
      string _name =_col["Name"].ToString();
      string _anotherField =_col["anotherField"].ToString();

      TbleUser newUser = new TbleUser(){
         name = _name 
         anotherField  = _anotherField 
      };

      db.tbl_User.Add(newUser);
      db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
```